# How to auto-generate a formula down a column that has a space in between?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I hope my question makes sense. What I'm trying to do is create a column where every second line refers to a column that is single spaced. I feel like I should just be able to write out a few lines of what I want and then auto-generate the rest with the corner drag thing, but the reference to the column I want to use won't stay in numerical order. I'll type out 4 lines, drag it down, and it will accumulate the spaces along with the filled cells. I've attached an image below of what I'm looking for.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test whether the row in which the formula is located is even, and if so use INDEX() with some math to ensure the correct row is returned:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),INDEX(D:D,(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained this. I just used the 1-6 as an example. The reference column will have road lengths, so they will always vary. I'm looking for a direct reference to the column, but the formula column will have a space between each cell.

Comment: This formula does not care what is in the column.  It will put a blank in the odd rows and then it will put each row in the reference column in the even rows.

Comment: If you want `=D1` type you will need to put each formula in manually.

Comment: Okay, I thought the numbers had to do something with adding numbers together to create a list of numbers in numerical order. Sorry about that, my experience with excel is limited. So I added an additional photo to the question. How would I create a formula in the left column that would reference to the column on the right?

Comment: Not seeing the additional photo.

Comment: Should be there now.

Comment: change the `D:D` to `N:N` and the `+2` to `+3` as that indicates the first row of the lookup values.

Comment: Put the formula in C26 and copy/drag down.

Comment: OKay, I'll  try that. I'll let you know how it works. Thanks

Comment: Sir, you are a life saver. Thank you very much!